# Non static method error on back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to add a back button to app but when i add the code i get the "Non static method 'canGoBack() cannot be referenced from a static context" error.  I have read several stack articles about this error but have not been able to solve it.  Any ideas please?

```
package com.test;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button push;

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceive invoked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);


        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);;
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx// ");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


        push = (Button)findViewById(R.id.senPushB);
        push.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return (true);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(WebView.canGoBack()){
            WebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyCustomReceiver.intentAction));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        JSONObject obj;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("alert", "hello!");
            obj.put("action", MyCustomReceiver.intentAction);
            obj.put("customdata","My message");

            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();

            // Push the notification to Android users
            query.whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android");
            push.setQuery(query);
            push.setData(obj);
            push.sendInBackground(); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(WebView.canGoBack()){
        WebView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
You should call `canGoBack()` and `goBack()` for the webview *instance* that you're using (move to the previous view). This is also why the method is declared at the instance level and not at the class level (static)

Comment: Great Solution. Worked for me :)

Comment: Also, I think WebView is not the public variable instantiated in the MainActivity class.

This same issue was happening to me but I realized (bad naming convention) that it was public WebView webView;

Answer (score 2):

canGoBack is an instance (non-static) method.  It can only be called on an instance of the WebView class.  WebView is the class.  Calling WebView.function() only works if function is a static function.  You need to get the instance of the WebView and call it on that.

For the record, the difference between a static and instance method-  a static method may not use any non-static data.  An instance method can.  Static data only has 1 copy per class.  Non-static data has 1 copy per instance of the class.